# How to structure a large typescript file?

Tags: typescript

we are using Typescript instead of simple JavaScript since around 6 month.

At the moment our code is growing (large application) and some typescript files are around 3000 to 5000 lines of code.

1 File is mostly 1 view in our frontend (e.g. historyView.cshtml has a history.ts). But some views on our frontend are really big and can do a lot of nice UI work.

An example:

history.ts

```
namespace history
{
    // 10 base functions here


   export namespace zoomfunction
   {
        // 10 more functions here
   }

   export namespace chartfunctions
   {
        // 10 more functions here
   }

   // Repeat this 10 times with more namespaces and functions... 
}
```

How to organize this in a better way then 5000 lines of code?
I read about splitted namespaces in files or modules - which is "best practice"?

Answer (score 0):

Creating single file with tons of code in it is definitely a bad way of doing it. And I think you should go with *modules* instead of *namespaces*. (You may look about modules [here](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) for example.)

As a result you'd have file structure similar to this:

```
src
└── history
    ├── zooming
    ├── charts
    ├── <...>
    └── index.ts
```

Then in your app file you could just import the history module like this:

```js
import * as history from './history';
```